# How to properly address "Graf zu"?

Tags: letter, person-names

Here is a simple question from a person with a limited knowledge in German.

Currently I'm writing a letter to a person who has a title of "Graf zu" someplace. Now how would you properly address him? *Dear Sir* or *Dear Graf zu ...*?

Comment: There is no such title in Germany, any more. It can only be a name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In German you traditionally wrote "Sehr geehrter Herr Graf zu XXX,...".

Nowadays you can simply write "Sehr geehrter Graf zu XXX,...". And only a chauffeur or butler are supposed to use "Herr Graf" without the name. Nobility  was abolished by the Weimar Republic in 1919. No new titles were to be awarded and existing titles were  to be considered as part of the name.

Some links are [here](http://www.wer-weiss-was.de/theme143/article1285064.html), [here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adelstitel)  and [here](http://www.korrekturen.de/forum.pl/md/read/id/3192/sbj/freiherren-grafen-und-so-weiter/) .(I added the first link because it contains the real thing: an answer to your question written by an actual Graf von Walderdorff !)

PS: Actually your question is about English and might be asked on English Language and Usage (http://english.stackexchange.com). You might start your letter according to the German rules above as a sign of respect and continue in English...

Comment: Since the nobility was abolished, as you say, there is no such thing as an `actual Graf`.

Comment: @user unknown: But there is an actual Graf von Walderdorff, i.e. a person with that name. Goerges Elencwajg did not claim that he is an actual Graf. +1 for the answer by the way.

Comment: @OregonGhost: read it again. What else shall 'an actual Graf von Walderdorff!' mean? Or is Berti-Vogts-Deutsch meanwhile an official language doctrine? "Von einem Lothar Matthaeus muss hier mehr kommen!"? The name, as an unique identifier in the context, would be used "written by Hein Graf von Walderdorff" or "by the author Detlef Graf von W.". If he is well known "by Graf von W." would be sufficient.

Comment: @user unknown: If you really want to go the nitpicking route, it's not Berti-Vogts-Deutsch, of course, since the sentence is in English :P Just kidding. I get your point, but this is not a formal text. Just read the sentence as "someone who actually has Graf in his name because one of his ancestors was actually a Graf". Your (formally better) suggestions, on the other hand, wouldn't get the point across Georges Elencwajg was trying to make, namely to emphasize that someone whose family lost the title and has it now just in the name says how it should be written correctly.

Comment: 1) Well, somebody who is affected directly might not be a neutral source, but, on the other hand, could have informed himself intensively. -- 2) Berti-Vogts-Deustsch isn't much better, if you translate it to English. It is `the` Sgt. Pepper Band, not `a` Sgt. Pepper Band, and would be sth. written by `the` Graf zu Grevenbroich (I don't find room for `actual` here), not by `an actual` Graf Dracula.

Comment: Somehow, the reasoning here does not seem to add up: "Nobility was abolished", yes. Which is why "existing titles [are] to be considered as part of the name". Thus, "Graf zu XXX" is the name (that happens to contain spaces), and *omitting* "Herr" is akin to writing "Sehr geehrter Hauk" instead of "Sehr geehrter Herr Hauk". The only way to omit "Herr" and just go with "Sehr geehrter Graf zu XXX" is if you *do* consider "Graf" a title.

Comment: @userunknown It seems you are an actual friend of correctness.